# Summarize array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm mainly programming in language that used for business systems, and there is a useful built-in function that can sum an array. For example, we've got array like this:

```
red | 1
red | 1
green | 1
orange | 2
orange | 1
orange | 1
blue | 1
```

After using summarizing function we get

```
red | 2
green | 1
orange | 4
blue | 1
```

Is it equivalent function in php?

**UPD.**

```
$array = array('red'=>1,'red'=>2,'green'=>1....);
```

Comment: How exactly does the array look like? If in the first example the left side are keys and the right side the values, then this is not possible. A key can only exist **once** in an array.

Comment: What is the array structure? You can not have two identical keys in array

Comment: that array would be invalid (i.e., while PHP allows you to define an array with multiple identical keys, later element will overwrite other elements with the same key). As @Felix said, keys must be unique, you can't have two "red's" in array.

Comment: Since you're talking about BI, shouldn't this data be stored in a DB? If so, use queries to summarize/aggregate the data.

Answer (score 3):

In php

```
red | 1
red | 1
green | 1
orange | 2
orange | 1
orange | 1
blue | 1
```

This kind of array is not possible. PHP array can not have multiple index keys with the same name. It will override the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

As said, an array like

```
array('red'=>1,'red'=>2,'green'=>1....);
```

is not possible. Try it and make a [**`print_r`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). You will see that there is only one `red` entry with value `2` (or what ever the last value is). The last one will overwrite the previous ones.

Depending on how you create the array, you can either sum the value on the fly, e.g.

```
for(...) {

    if(!isset($array[$color])) {
        $array[$color] = 0;
    }

    $array[$color] += $value;

}
```

or create a multidimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    'red'=> array(1,2),
    'green'=> array(1),
    ...
);
```

You can then [**`array_map`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to loop over it and compute the sums of each entry with [**`array_sum`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$newarray = array_map('array_sum', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial array should contain only values. You can use `array_values()` for that. After that you can count the values with `array_count_values()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: He cannot use `array_values()`, as the result would be meaningless (or the same as input, if it is 2D array).

Comment: What do you think the array looks like? He does not want to count all the `1` but sum the values based on the color.

Comment: that was added later on to the question :) an incorrect array to be precise

Answer (score 0):

supposed you have array like this:

```
$array = array(
    'red | 1',
    'red | 1',
    'green | 1',
    'orange | 2',
    'orange | 1',
    'orange | 1',
    'blue | 1'
);
```

You can process it this way:

```
<?php
//process the array data
$temp_output = array();
foreach( $array as $raw)
{
    list($name, $value) = array_map('trim', explode("|", $raw));
    if( !isset($temp_output[ $name ] ) )
        $temp_output[ $name ] = (int)$value;
    else
        $temp_output[ $name ] += (int)$value;
}
//now, print the value
foreach( $temp_output as $key => $data)
{
    echo "{$key} | {$data}\n";
}
?>
```